# Connecting Azure Cosmos DB with Mongo and Flask

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

my question is more about setting up and adding data.
I am making the first project with Mongo DB on VS Code and can not find solution what to do next.
Google said Instal Cosmos DB, so I did but what next? Does it talk to Flask already? I am lost, need help from someone who works on Flask and MongoDB on VSCode!
Feel like an idiot now!

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

from cocktails.main.views import main
app.register_blueprint(main)
```

Comment: If you are using a hosted service like CosmosDB the connection string (`MONGO_URI` in your example code) would be a cloud URI with credentials rather than `localhost`: [Connect to Cosmos DB](https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/connect-mongodb-account). I would look for a tutorial to get started as this is a broader question than just configuring a connection. Also note that CosmosDB is an emulation of MongoDB and does differ in features and behaviour. If you are new to MongoDB I would consider using a service like MongoDB Atlas so all of the expected features are available.

Comment: Hi @Stennie, I have done that just yesterday and I think that I will switch to Atlas. Will be way easier. It`s hard to be newbie so many questions so many confusions. Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it talk to Flask already?

Hi,Patrycja. Quick answer is YES!  I follow your description and do the steps in this [document1](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) and [document2](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create Flask project which accesses Cosmos DB Mongo API.

My app.py looks like below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "******"
mongo = PyMongo(app)
print(mongo.db)

@app.route("/")
def home_page():
    items = mongo.db.test.find()
    for item in items:
        name = item["name"]
        return name
```

I use Cosmos DB Mongo API, the sample data as below:

[image]

Run the command `python -m flask run`: ,get output:

[image]

The key point is `"MONGO_URI"`, it is the connection string:

[image]

If you concern about the cost,you could use [Cosmos DB Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) for your test. Surely, as @Stennie mentioned in the comment,cosmos db mongo api only supports partial features of Mongo DB. But if your work is only limited to simple queries, you could use it.Otherwise,please consider using Mongo Atlas.

Comment: Thanks, @Jay I was away from the keyboard yesterday. Yes, that helped me to understand the logic but your right that the best solution is to use MongoDB Atlas which is way easier.  Really appreciate your help and big Thank you.